# Regex to validate a string with 3 fields/groups, each field/group will need further validation

Tags: regex, validation, sed

I have a single line:

```
file:///var/run/storm/blah.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology exclamation-topology
```

Consists of 3 (no more, no less) fields/groups separated by one space.

1. First field needs to begin with either `file://` or `hdfs://`
2. Second field is has not limitations.
3. The third field cannot contain `.` `/` `:` `\\`

I am used to using several regex to work something like this out with some  language logic around it... as in `cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -e 'regex here'`.  But the application I am using is not allowing this and I am having a really hard time trying to figure out how to do this.

I tried something along the lines of `/(\b[^\s]+\b){3,3}/g` but if I add a fourth field and it has any digit, ., -, etc it will match that. I also have no clue how to perform a regex on a specific field like the first or the third.

I cannot use `cut | sed` as it needs to be a single regex. The application is Cloudera Manager and unfortunately their documentation here is poor. All it say is that it is a regex. If you go to the following url and look for the type "string" it will show that you can use the "conformRegex" followed by a regex to validate the string. [Cloudera SDL parameter types](https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/Service-Descriptor-Language-Reference#parameterTypes)

How do I create a single regex to do all of the above functions?

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: added question to post

Comment: What regular expressions did you try? What version of regex does your "application" support? What about your `cut | sed` attempt did it not allow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just string regexp's together into one regexp to tell the app exactly what you want, with start and end "anchoring" and "not" character groups:

```
^(file:\/\/|hdfs:\/\/)[^ ]* [^ ]+ (\\?[^./:\\ ]+)+\\?$
```

Note how it only allows 2 spaces (all other expressions exclude spaces).

Comment: There appears to be a space after the 3rd "field" in your sample data above. Without the space regexr on the above regexp matches. If (optional) trailing space is "allowed" like that, insert `\s*` before the `$` in the above.

Comment: Opps, the regex is matching any \ It needs to match only a \\.

Comment: What does that mean? Give an example of what is matching that should not match (or vice versa) please. (Are you saying the 3rd "field" can contain \ but not \\ ?)

Comment: Yes the third field can contain a \ but not a \\

my-third-field\and\more - valid

my-third-field\\and\\\more - invalid

Comment: OK, updated the answer to take care of that requirement. (Only restriction is that field 3 cannot consist of a single lone \ ).

Answer (score 0):

if awk is allowed then validation can be done easily as below 
create awk file (myvalidation.awk)

```
# myvalidation.awk
{
  # assume all records are good
  v_bad_record = 0;

  # set the bad record flag to 1 if first field not starting with file:// or hdfs://
  if ( $1 !~ /^file:\/\// &&  $1 !~ /^hdfs:\/\// )
  v_bad_record = 1;

  # set the bad record if 3rd field has any of . : \ /
  if ( $3 ~ /[\.:\/\\]/ )
  v_bad_record = 1;

  # print bad record only
  if ( v_bad_record == 1 )
  print $0;

  # if you want to print good record then comment above 2 lines and uncomment below 2 lines
  # if ( v_bad_record == 0 )
  # print $0;

}
```

Then run the command as below it will print all records which failed validation

```
$ awk -f myvalidation.awk datafile.txt
```